# Social Media - Link Preview - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, links, social-media

So - here is the issue - link previews of CiviCRM pages have some issues. Any idea as to why this is?

Example: https://tarabnyc.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Finfo&reset=1&id=114

On wordpress block embed:
[image]

On Facebook Embed a bit better but the page title is still CiviCRM - when facebook feels like it - we can edit the title - which is great, but when other people share the page - its not so great.

[image]

Comment: Can you try this patch? https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-wordpress/pull/158

Comment: That fixes it - now I have another issue which I don't think is CiviCRM related - the link preview looks good - then changes when posted - pretty sure thats a fb issue.

Comment: Yeah, IIRC you have to force FB to refresh its Open Graph resources. FWIW, the patch will not affect WordPress post embeds.